# How to make gradient tool annotators snap to grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, grids, creative-cloud

I'd like to have precise control over a gradient fill. From Expression Studio I'm used to the gradient tool annotator to automatically snap to a grid. By default, the Adobe Illustrator gradient annotator happily ignore the "Snap to Grid" setting in the View menu. Do I need to toggle a special option to make the gradient annotator respect the grid?

Any help is very much appreciated.

**edit**

A screenshot as requested:
[image]

Comment: do you have any screenshot showing what the problem is?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "gradient handle"? Do you mean the annotator (see CirclsB's answer)? Or do you mean the handles of the shape the gradient is applied to? The gradient panel gives more precise control than the annotator does.

Comment: Yes, sorry, didn't know about the terminology.

Comment: @CircleB is correct. There's no mechanism to snap the gradient annotator to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option, that I know of, for that. :-(

It seems like a very good thing to have, I'll submit a feature request [here](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform).